# How message get separate from Http request object in RESTful web service?

Tags: web-services, servlets, restful-architecture

Can anyone let me know, how message entity get separated from the HttpServletRequest object in RESTful service?

My understanding from Servlet programming is, whenever we will call doPost() method, here server thread will pass HttpServletRequest object from which we will access the header or data.

But in case of RESTful web service, whenever we will access any resource(method), it will just pass the message object(in form of string or mapped the passed JSON Object to class and pass corresponding class object to called method).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it fully answers the question, but to extract the body from an `HttpServletRequest`, you can use either `getInputStream` or `getReader`, which provides you with a way to read the body of the HTTP request.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Cdelmas. but I got the answered what i was looking for. There is messageBodyReader  which take care of reading message entity from HTTP request entity and map to the method parameters to the called resource. and in the same way messageBodyWriter which take care of writing data returned from resource to the http response.